# undefined function in the same js file

Tags: javascript, requirejs

```
define(function() {
  return {
    show: function(msg) {
      alert(msg);
    },
    showing: function(msg) {
      adding(10); //it throws up an exception saying that adding is undefined.
    },
    adding: function(x) {
      return x + 10;
    }
  };
});
```

I have tried to switch adding above the showing function but it doesnt seem to work as well. Am i misunderstanding something? I am still very new to require js.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is more of an issue with the JavaScript prototypical language than Require. It's a matter of the adding function's scope. Try this to get it working, then I suggest you look quite a bit into scoping with JS.

> ```
> define(function() {
>   function addTenTo(x) {
>     return x + 10;
>   }
>
>   return { 
>     show: function(msg) {
>         alert(msg);
>     },
>
>     showing: function(msg) {
>         return addTenTo(10);
>     },
>
>     adding: addTenTo   // as suggested by gp
>   };
> ```
>
> });

Comment: how about exposing `addTenTo` itself. `adding: addTenTo` instead of defining a new function.

Comment: @gp. Even better! Updated.

Answer (score 2):

Call `adding` with `this.`

```
showing: function(msg) {
  this.adding(10);
}
```

**this** will refer to the object you are returning which defines showing and adding methods.

Answer (score 1):

Your *adding* function is not in a scope of *showing*. Basically *adding* is just a **property of object**, not the function name which can be called.

```
this.adding(10);
```

So, we are calling *adding* as an Object property inside of the Object scope (that is why we are using **this** keyword)

Comment: So how do i actually use the function adding? within the same js file. I understand i can actually place the output as a parameter. but i am thinking along the lines of programming languages which seperate them as functions

Comment: `this.adding(10);` **this** will refer to the object you are returning which defines showing and adding methods.

Comment: As @gp. said, you are returning an Object with property adding - so use it as a property as much as you want in the actual Object scope (with THIS keyword).

Comment: @AlexShumilov you'd better add this to your answer. Don't just leave the most important part in comments.

Comment: I moved my comment to answer. @AlexShumilov answer can be marked as answer please go ahead.

Comment: @gp. I think yours is an actual answer, I have too general information.